# countdowntimer with sound.is it possible?

Tags: android

I want to ask a question I have put the timer  to count down from 10:00 min..I want it when it goes at 2 min to put a sound for 10 seconds like an error sound or alarm sound is that possible and if it is can I have some help plz??

Comment: 1) Yes it is possible. 2) Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Is that a sufficient answer? If not, your question is too vague and broad in scope (*can I have some help plz??* is not a specific question), and you should [edit] to make it more clear what you're asking. This is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, all you have to do to check the remaining time and play the sound accordingly:

```
private static final int Two_Seconds = 120000;
public void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds,10000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            if(millisUntilFinished <= Two_Seconds){
               // display your sound
            }
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
    countdownButton.setText("PAUSE");
    timerRunning = true;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    countdownText = findViewById(R.id.countdown_text);
    countdownButton = findViewById(R.id.countdown_button);

    countdownButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           startstop();
        }
    });
    updateTimer();
}
public void startstop(){
   if(timerRunning){
       stopTimer();
   }else {
       startTimer();
   }
}
public void startTimer(){
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeLeftInMilliseconds,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timeLeftInMilliseconds = millisUntilFinished;
            updateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
    countdownButton.setText("PAUSE");
    timerRunning = true;
}
public void stopTimer (){
    countDownTimer.cancel();
    countdownButton.setText("START");
    timerRunning = false;
}
public void updateTimer (){
    int minutes = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds / 60000;
    int seconds = (int) timeLeftInMilliseconds % 60000 / 1000;

    String timeLeftText;

    timeLeftText = "" + minutes;
    timeLeftText += ":";
    if(seconds <7)timeLeftText +=0;
    timeLeftText += seconds;

    countdownText.setText(timeLeftText);
}
```

}

Comment: this is my code its 7 min not 10 and when the time goes at 2 min I want to put a sound!!

Comment: Although this code answer the question . You should prefer explaining it exactly what is happening . just pasting code would not help any of developer not even you . Thx